# Does WSASend send all WSABUF buffers as a single packet?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock2

The title probably explains itself best.

Anyway, I have a data buffer received from an another source, and I want to send it in a single UDP packet that contains a sequence number (as the first byte) -> I want to add the sequence number to the given buffer!

Instead of allocating a new buffer, settings it's size to size+4, setting the sequence number as the first byte and copying the data into the buffer, I would like to just use the scatter gather mechanism of WSA.

Sadly though, no WSA document specifies explicitly that WSASend guarantees that all buffer will be sent a single packet (The packet size will be held as < 1500 bytes).

Can I be certain that it will work that way? Or should I re-build the packet?

Best,
Daniel

Comment: If UDP could fragment messages then it would be impossible to receive them because they might arrive completely scrambled.

Comment: @usr: But UDP (or rather IP) _can_ fragment messages. It is preferrable not to make it do that since it will amplify the effects of packet loss, but it sure is possible. UDP can, and will, send any datagram up to 65535-40 bytes using 1500-byte (or a similar size) fragments.

Comment: You will never get a partial UDP message from your OS. If that was possible then all contents could end up garbled because later fragments might arrive after earlier ones (because of UDP's lack of ordering). That would allow any message to be scrambled into any possible permutation. Impossible.; I think IP fragmentation is used so that fragmentation is transparent to UDP. Not sure, doesn't matter. The OS guarantees you intact UDP messages.

Comment: @usr you are mistaken. UDP packets can be fragmented and reassembled in the correct order by the IP layer. There is enough information non each fragment to do that. What doesn't happen in UDP is retransmission of lost fragments, which results in complete loss of the entire datagram.

Comment: @EJP I'm not saying they aren't fragmented and reassembled. This is what I'm saying: fragmentation is transparent to apps receiving packets. You never receive a partial packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is documented in a round-about way:

> For message-oriented sockets, do not exceed the maximum message size of the underlying provider, which can be obtained by getting the value of socket option SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE. If the data is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol the error WSAEMSGSIZE is returned, and no data is transmitted.

So clearly it combines the data from the buffers to make a single UDP packet.  If it didn't then there would no point in returning the WSAEMSGSIZE error.

Comment: It could return WSAEMSGSIZE if a single buffer exceeds the size, even if each buffer is a new datagram.

Comment: You say nay, I say yay, the OP will say okay.